# Issue with swift framework import

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created a swift framework.
In this framework i have some swift file and one category in objective-C (so there is the .h and .m files).
I successfully build my framework, but when i import it into another project, only the method from my category (written in objective-C) are visible. If i try to use any swift class i got an error "Use of unresolved identifier".

I have checked the following points in my framework project :

- all my swift class are public `public class Toto`
- i have set the **build settings - packaging - defines module** param to **yes**

In my project where the framework is imported, i have the following code :

```
import UIKit
import myframework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        toto()
    }

    func toto() {
        let data = NSData()
        data.isGzippedData()
        var client = Client ()
        NSLog("ok");

    }
}
```

I have an error "Use of undeclared identifier" for the line `var toto = Client ()`, but in my swift framework the class `Client` is public and its default constructor is public.

However, if i comment this line, the code works fine, even if the method `isGzippedData` is declared and implement in my framework (but in objective-C).

How can i use the swift class from my framework into my project ?